Error: [readCachedProjectGraph] ERROR: No cached ProjectGraph is available
I just created a project using nx 19.5.7 and after that I tried to serve my app and I ran into with this problem:

Maybe problem in deprecated version of CLI
My package.json:
{
  "name": "@paint/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nx/cypress": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/eslint": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/jest": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/js": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/react": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/vite": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/web": "19.5.7",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.5.7",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.9.1",
    "@swc/cli": "~0.3.12",
    "@swc/core": "~1.5.7",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.11",
    "@testing-library/react": "15.0.6",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.16.9",
    "@types/react": "18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.16.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "^1.3.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.1",
    "cypress": "^13.13.0",
    "eslint": "~8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.13.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "jsdom": "~22.1.0",
    "nx": "19.5.7",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.5.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0",
    "vitest": "^1.3.1"
  }
}


I have tried to reset cache of nx but it didn't solve the problem.
